# Does fabric support json rpc like invoking?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The hyperledger fabric project supports nodejs sdk, but I do not know if it supports javascript embedded in html. Or if hyperledger supports implicit Json rpc, that will be nice. Any suggestions? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger fabric uses gRPC and not JSON-RPC as a communication middleware.